# sql Query to get active Columnnames of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with sql server 2008.I have 2 tables table1 contains,

```
id  name   chk1   chk2    chk3 
1   aaa     0      0       1
2   bbb     2      2       1
3   ccc     1      0       2
```

table2 contains

```
chk_code  chk_name  flag 
  CH1       chk1      1
  CH2       chk2      0
  CH3       chk3      1
```

i want to get the result set like,

```
Column_Name 
id  
name   
chk1   
chk3
```

the check having flag value 0 doesnot appear in the resultset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
with x as (
    select *
    from sys.columns c
    left join table2 t2 on c.name = t2.chk_name 
    where c.object_id = object_id('table1')
)
select name
from x
where flag = 1 or flag is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using unpivot... But problem with unpivot is all unpivoted column name must be of same data type that to same size... if that is okay then you can use unpivot like this

```
SELECT Column_Name
FROM (SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
   tab1) p
UNPIVOT
   (tab1 FOR Column_Name  IN 
      ([id], [name], [chk1], [chk2], [chk3])
)AS unpvt) AS vv WHERE Column_Name NOT IN 
(SELECT chk_name FROM tab2 WHERE flag = 0)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e4793/1/0) of above